# Why does one of the two fragments in an activity take up the whole screen during run time?

Tags: android, android-fragments

my activity_main.xml has two framelayouts that acts as containers for two fragments .When i run each fragment individually ,they run good .when i try to initialize and display both fragments ,one of the fragments called **recents fragment** is taking the full screen view .

when i run this fragment individually ,it takes full screen view instead of running in its own container.

and when i try to initialize my second fragment after initializing **recents fragment** i get an error**No view found for id 0x7f070044 (com.example.diary:id/allnotesfragment) for fragment BlankFragment{7eb6bf4 (bc0fee9d-4a46-4e2b-ab31-d060c0ec14ae) id=0x7f070044}**

activity code where i initialize both the fragments are is given below

```
package com.example.diary;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

int j;
List<NotesEntry> entries;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
NotesDatabase db;
int numofitems;
String notesdata = "new_notes";
String defaultnotes = "old_notes";
Context c = this;
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
RecentsFragment recentsFragment;
ActivityMainBinding binding;
String textfortest;
int id;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecentsFragment recentsFragment=new RecentsFragment();
    BlankFragment blankFragment=new BlankFragment();
  fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.recentsfragment,recentsFragment).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.allnotesfragment,blankFragment).commit();



}
}
```

its layout xml is

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recentsfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.618"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"></FrameLayout>

<view
    android:id="@+id/view"
    class="android.widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-51dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/allnotesfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="327dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>
```

i tried to implement it on other layouts too ,but the result is same.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is most likely incorrect. Try something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/some_view"/>


    <view
            android:id="@+id/some_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_container1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_container2"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/some_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i have tried it too before no use .the" recents fragment" takes up the whole screen no matter how i assign views

Comment: Try again. What answer are you looking for? BTW...

android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

... are the same thing, same with right and end.

Try using the layout I have provided, just tested it and it works fine.

Try simplifying it as much as you can take everything out but the minimum and then once you have it working you can add all the other stuff back in.

Comment: After spending a lot of time ,I figured out the solution . I used databinding in my fragment to assign data to recyclerview ....in "Databindingutils.setContentView(getActivity(),R.layout.)" .here in the first argument I used getActivity ,that is causing the problem ...but am not sure why I can't use databinding in that way ...

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time on it, I found that the problem is not with the layout but with the fragment itself.

In the `oncreateView` method of a fragment, I used `databinding` to refer to view instead of `findViewById()` and I have implemented a wrong way of databinding.

so by implementing databinding in the following way, I solved my problem.

```
  fragmentBlankBinding = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
  fragmentBlankBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  fragmentBlankBinding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  view=fragmentBlankBinding.getRoot();
  return view;
```

Note: you need not refer to any layouts using this method as the layout is automatically fetched from databinding layout file of your fragment.

Hope it helps someone